# Converting .OBJ File Text to a GameObject in Unity?

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, import

So what I am trying to do is instantiating a .obj file locally stored on the device **AFTER BUILD**. I have searched for hours but in vain... 
I already managed to make a file explorer in unity, which returns the URL of the selected .obj file. Then I use WWW(string url) load the object.

```
WWW bundleRequest = new WWW(@"file://" + pathName);
```

To this point, everything is perfect.
And here is my question: Is there a way to convert the text of the file, so `bundleRequest.text` to an instantiable GameObject **AFTER BUILD**? Through any means possible: APIs, extensions, etc.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Dont be daft and get the text representation of your obj file, use the downloadhandler to get the raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This asset has helped me before, Runtime OBJ Importer, it's free too!

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-obj-importer-49547

Comment: Oh thank you. Ive been searching for days on how to do this but og course I didnt search on the AssetsStore...